# Negative energy solutions Dirac equation without radation field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation

In the book "Relativistic Quantum Mechanics" by Bjorken and Drell in Chapter 5.1 page 64 there is the following statement about the problem of negative solutions to the Dirac equation:

> By their very existence the negative-energy solutions require a massive reinterpretation of the Dirac theory in order to prevent atomic electrons from making radiative transitions into negative-energy states and cascading down to oblivion. This is no problem if we completely neglect interaction of the electrons with the radiation field.

I'm not sure of understanding this statement. Why is the issue of negative energy only related to the radiative field. Couldn't there be another mechanism by which the energy could infinitely tumble down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in a Free Theory. If you remember that the negative energy states mentioned are also eigenstates of the (free)-Hamiltonian, you get that they are 'protected' from decaying into lower energy states. If you have some interaction, I believe 'any' interaction, not only electromagnetic (e.g. Yukawa), you should be able to access these states.

On a more technical side, I believe that you need that the Hamiltonian operator to be bounded from below( no free Hamiltonian negative eigenvalues), but I haven't studied that yet I so I can't comment any further.